# How disable go to next field and submit Form on keyCode == “enter” (13) on Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I have a form

```
<form action="#" class="form">
<input class="form__input" type="text" name="name" required>
<input class="form__input" type="tel" name="tel" required>
<button class="form__button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and jQuery code

```
$('.form .form__input').keydown(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).blur();
            return false;
        }
});
```

See in action: https://codepen.io/maxbeat/pen/XWXGZLM

I want only blur input field after press key Enter. PC and iOs devices work good, but Android after press key Enter go to next input field, how disable this?

Comment: OP, if you found solution, please post it here

Answer (score -1):

please try following code hope this will helpful to you

```
function checkCR(evt) {
            var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
            var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
            if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type == "textarea") && (node.name == "field1"))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        document.onkeypress = checkCR;
```

Comment: will you please let me know in which browser you are testing on android>

Comment: http://output.jsbin.com/omatip/1  Check this page this will helpful or try blur event

Comment: it is impossible check my problem on this page because only one input and nothing more